# Why can`t i use $scope.feedback.myChannel inside my controller if i can use it in my html page?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-forms

I have a form using angularJs, all code is available on my plunker at the end of the question.

inside my controller i have

```
$scope.showTelfield= false; $scope.showEmailfield= false;
```

in my form and for telephone field and email field i`m using:

```
ng-show="showTelField"  ng-show="showEmailField"
```

these values should be true if the user select it from the select options as it is designed inside the controller.

in html

```
<select class="form-control c-select" name="select" ng-model="feedback.myChannel" ng-options="channel.value as channel.label for channel in channels">
 <option value="">Select a method</option>
 </select>
```

in controller:

```
 $scope.feedback = {
  myChannel: "",
  firstName: '',
  lastName: '',
  agree: false,
  email: ''
};
$scope.channels = [{
  value: "Tel",
  label: "Tel"
}, {
  value: "Email",
  label: "Email"
}, {
  value: "Tel & Email",
  label: "Tel & Email"
}];


//Telling browser to view telephone or Email feild if needed..
    if($scope.feedback.myChannel === "Tel" || $scope.feedback.myChannel === "Tel & Email"){
        $scope.showTelField = true }

    if($scope.feedback.myChannel === "Email" || $scope.feedback.myChannel === "Tel & Email"){
        $scope.showEmailField = true }
```

the value of $scope.feedback.myChannel changes from an empty string to "Tel", "Email" or "Tel & Email" based on the user choice and i'm showing that inside an extra div only for developing purpose to make sure they change on user's selection.

but all the if statements don't work although the value of $scope.feedback.myChannel changes according to the displaying div i'm making for development.
any idea why is that?

you can see my code in my plunker
[Here is my plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/L12ltpi27VAIDkFHKHwX?p=preview)

and here is a screenshot of the the page
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the `ifs` that you have in your controller will only be called when page loads, after that `angular` ignores it **unless** you put your logic inside a `function` on the `$scope`.

To detect a change in your `<select>` you should use [**`ngChange`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) directive, like this:

**View:**

```
<select ng-change="change()" class="form-control c-select" name="select" ng-model="feedback.myChannel" ng-options="channel.value as channel.label for channel in channels">
```

**JS:**

```
$scope.change = function() {
  console.log($scope.feedback.myChannel);
}
```

Then those variables that you're trying to use to manipulate your data (`showTelField`, `showEmailField`) can be simply replaced by a directive, *i.e.* [**`ngSwitch`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch), so you can have something like this:

```
<div ng-switch="feedback.myChannel">
  <div class="form-group " ng-class="{'has-error': !feedbackForm.telnum.$pristine && feedback.tel.number == '' || feedback.tel.areacode == ''}" ng-switch-when="Tel">
  ...
  </div>
  <div class="form-group has-feedback" ng-class="{'has-error': !feedbackForm.email.$pristine && feedback.email == '' || feedbackForm.email.$invalid }" ng-switch-when="Email">
  ...
  </div>
  <div ng-switch-when="Tel & Email">
  ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Also I'd suggest you to use [**`ngIf`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) directive instead of `ngShow` in some parts of your `code` as a good practice.

Take a look on the forked [**DEMO**](http://plnkr.co/edit/78T4L5opYAojYpr4nXEp?p=preview).

Comment: Thank you .. please know that:         ng-show="feedback.agree && (feedback.myChannel== 'Tel' || feedback.myChannel == 'Tel & Email') "> also works!       Y?       i can reach the wanted result by few solutions but my Question is how am i able to use feedback.myChannel in html and cant use it as $scope.feedback.myChannel in the controller? and when u say :  there's no way to showTelField and showEmailField be true since you aren't setting them to true .. but when u select an option u r setting feedback.myChannel to a value .. please go to ur plunker and use ng-show as above.

Comment: and without all that,, look into that displaying div on right side it shows that feedback.myChannel takes a value upon selection.. and that is what my if statements say .. change showTelField and showEmailField to true if feedback.myChannel takes a value. !!!

Comment: Well, I'm not sure it works.. I didn't even tested because `ng-show` is a bad practice, you should use `ngIf` or **BETTER** `ngSwitch` which was made exactly for this kind of thing. And for your question the answer is: **no**, the values (`showTelField` & `showEmailField`) can't be true, since you didn't make no way to make them true.. what's the problem with the solution above? What do you mean when you say **"I can't use the variable in my controller"**????

Comment: i`m looking for answer not for a solution. Thank you very much for ur efforts ..   :))

Comment: So a solution isn't an answer?

Comment: no mate.. as i achieved the solution long ago in few ways .. my question is very specific why the value of $scope.feedback.myChannel does not change when feedback.myChannel changes in the form?  i want to understand not to find a solution.. thank you very much again u also introduced me to new solutions too.  :))

Comment: Let's go.. first of all, how are you trying to get this value in your controller? I don't see any directive there.. like `ngChange` or `ngSubmit` (to get it on submit).

Comment: didn`t get that, sorry.. u can see the code at my plunker

Comment: the rest of the chat here; http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117972/discussion-between-developer033-and-shireef-khatab

Answer (score 0):

It's better to trust the FormControl object, by changing `ng-show="feedback.agree"` to `ng-if="feedback.agree"` and making the select field `required`:

```
<div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1" ng-if="feedback.agree">
    <select class="form-control c-select" name="select" ng-model="feedback.myChannel" ng-options="channel.value as channel.label for channel in channels" required>
        <option value="">Select a method</option>
    </select>
    <span class="help-block" ng-show="invalidChannelSelection && feedback.myChannel == ''">Select a method</span>
</div>
```

And then you can disable the submit button based on the validity state of the form (I removed the `|| invalidChannelSelection` from the `ngDisabled` directive):

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" ng-disabled="feedbackForm.$invalid">Send Feedback</button>
```

Working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/un9BYMa81cqWOCyd4Vdj?p=preview

Comment: thank you, i looked into ur plunker and it doesnt show those fields on selecting an option.

Comment: and i guess i can't make select required in case if user doesn't want to be contacted so the form will always be invalid.. true!!   please also read my comment @developer33 below.. as i'm explaining more about my question.